# Show Option Menu Icon

Tags: android

I am having a problem showing the Option menu icon for devices that does not have Soft Key. When i tried the application to a 4.0.3 device without Soft Key I do not know how to open the Option Menu.

I have searched some answers and it said that Android Manifest (`minSdkVersion and TargetVersion`). this is the android manifest of the application:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

How do I open Option Menu in devices that have no Soft Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `android:targetSdkVersion` lower than 11, for example 10 (Android 2.3.3). If your `targetSDKversion` is set to `HoneyComb` or higher version the menu button won't appear on your device,because this versions of android uses ActionBar where should the icon appear (of course if you wrote that implementation).